# Kotlin foreachblock example

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to learn Kotlin and am having trouble with file.foreachblock function(https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/for-each-block.html).

Specifically I want to update the messageDigest with the byte array, but it is not clear to me how I would do this. Any examples would be great

something like

```
file.foreachblock(){ ->
  messageDigest.update(it.bytearray, 0, it.length);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lambda passed to `forEachBlock` must accept two parameters. First is a `ByteArray` buffer, and second is the number of bytes with actual data in that array.

```
file.forEachBlock { buffer, count ->
    messageDigest.update(buffer, 0, count)
}
```

Comment: it's al in the signature `action: (ByteArray, Int) -> Unit`